# Unable to push large metrics (500+) within a min to graphite via python (Socket)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, graphite

I have 5 MySQL slaves and 1 master, for each machine I'm collecting stats and pushing to graphite with python program. The script runs 6 threads (for each machine) and sends to the graphite through socket. I'm very clear that, I'm unable to push more than 70 stats at a time. Here's the program.

**ThreadSocketClient.py**

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import socket
import MySQLdb as Database
import logging
import sys
import time
from mysqlStats import status_keys
from mysqlStats import GRAPHITE_HOST, GRAPHITE_PORT

class MysqlGraphiteUtil(Thread):

def __init__(self,host,port,user,password):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    print current_thread
    self.host=host
    self.port=port
    self.user=user
    self.password=password
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.connect((GRAPHITE_HOST, GRAPHITE_PORT))

def run(self):
    self.connectDB()
    self.showStatus()
    self.sock.close()

def connectDB(self):
    try:
        self.db = Database.connect(
            host=self.host,
            port=self.port,
            user=self.user,
            passwd=self.password
        )
    except Exception, err:
        logging.exception(err)
        print err
        sys.exit()

    return self.db,self.host

def showStatus(self):
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
    self.cursor.execute("SHOW GLOBAL STATUS")
    data = self.cursor.fetchall()
    self.stats = dict()
    for key, value in data:
        if key in status_keys:
            self.stats[key] = value
    self.db.close()
    self.push_data(self.stats, self.host)

def push_data(self,stats, sname):
    for key, val in stats.iteritems():
        if val.isdigit():
            short = sname.replace('.', '_')
            message = 'mysql.' + short + '.' + key + ' ' + val + ' ' + '%d \n' % int(time.time())
            self.sock.send(message)
            self.sock.close()
```

The problem lies around in `push_data()`, when I put `time.sleep(0.30)` after `self.sock.close()` it's sending all the data but it's taking more than a minute (approx 2 min). It's of no use, since I'm collecting the metric per minute. Please help how can I speedup the socket connect and sending.

PS: Pls let me know if any details required from the supporting files, I shall post it.

Comment: Are you aware about existing tools like Diamond (https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond), that provide many collectors including MySQL?

Comment: `socket.send` returns the number of bytes sent, it does not guarantee that whole line is sent

Comment: socket is closed after first sent line

Comment: Apart from regular metrics, I'm sending custom metrics too, which other plugins won't support much. Btw, I've found the solution, I'm posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified with `tcpdump`that whether the server is consuming all the packets/data which I'm sending. It does as expected. So, confirmed that `socket` was not the problem.

As the next check, I wanted to completely verify the `carbon.conf` and found that `MAX_QUEUE_SIZE` was 500, increased that to 1000, but still there was discrepancy in total sent and total received.

Also found that `MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE=100`, I changed that to 1000 and it has worked !! This is the value which instructs graphite to create the max no. of whisper files per minute.

Comment: Are you on a LAN or switched network? If you are, keep in mind that you will only have one packet in flight per socket, so all the threads are doing is keeping the kernel's buffers full.

Comment: I'm on LAN. And the whole process was completed in 0.3 secs :)

Comment: Keep in mind that it can be a limiting factor. Good to know it wasn't in this case.